# Pandas Python UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, pandas, datareader

I'm just practicing writing codes for data extraction. I used the following code and it worked before. However, I've recently updated `pandas` and now it doesn't work and gives me an error.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data
data.DataReader(name = ["MSFT", "GOOG", "AAPL", "YHOO", "AMZN"], data_source = "google",
               start = "2010-01-01", end = "2016-12-31")`
```

Resulting in the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 46626: invalid start byte'
```

I've tried looking online here and used the `.encode('utf-8).strip()` at the end of each parameters to see if it works but it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue which is not yet fixed.

https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/424

Comment: thank you for sharing this. I will wait for the next fix. I'm new to PANDAS so will try out what the other members are posting

Answer (score 0):

try doing

```
.decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

instead of

```
.encode('utf-8).strip()
```

Comment: Hi Nitesh, where should I insert that code? I tried putting it at the end 

`data.DataReader(name = companies, data_source = "google",
               start = "2010-01-01", end = "2016-12-31").decode('unicode_escape').encode('ascii', 'ignore')` 

but returns the same error